# Fixed size window for Apache Beam

Tags: apache-beam

How to define window of fixed size (fixed number of items) in Apache Beam?

I know that we have

```
(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardMinutes(10))
```

but I do not care about time-only about number of items.

More details:
I am writing significant amount of data (53 gigabytes) to S3. Currently my proces uses

```
FileIO.<KV<...>writeDynamic()
.by(kv -> kv.getKey())
```

(grouping by key). This causes serve performance bottleneck, because of skewed key distribution. My total data size is 53Gb, but size of data for one key is 37Gb. This single key takes an hour to write (writing occurs on single executor, single thread, rest of cluster waits idle).

I do not need any special grouping. Ideally I want uniform distribution of data, so writing will happen concurrently and finish as soon as possible.

Comment: You would need a `GlobalWindow`, with a repeated trigger and `AfterCount`

Comment: If you are writing files I think you actually need them to be windowed and GlobalWindow would not work, but you can have the same trigger i mentioned earlier with FixedWindows

Answer (score 1):

Guaranteeing exactly equal sized grouping is fairly hard, but you can get pretty close by using hashes of your data modulo some constant as the keys.  For example:

```
FileIO.<KV<...>writeDynamic()
.by(kv -> kv.hashCode() % 530)
```

This will give roughly equal 100MB partitions.

Additionally, if you are using the DataflowRunner, you don't need to specify keys at all; the system will automatically group up the data, and dynamically rebalance the load to avoid stragglers.  For this, use FileIO.write() instead of FileIO.writeDynamic().